# Can't Figure Out Numbers In ConstantBuffers

Tags: hlsl

I am building up my skills with HLSL, one of the games I am learning it through has the line in it's shaders, say:

```
ConstantBuffer( 1, 7 )
{
    float4 test_var[10];
}
```

And I can't quite fully figure this out

I understand what's in the ConstantBuffer, it creating an array of float4s, but what I don't get is the (1,7) part of this and what the numbers do, I've played around with them and seen changing them does affect output, but haven't managed to find a definitive answer

Comment: What Shader Model is being used?

Comment: It might also be a custom shader preprocessor thing.